# Python Addressing Value in a List in a Dictionary; Making a variable 'literal'

Tags: python, list, variables, indexing, literals

I'm 100% sure that this is a basic task but the problem is that I have no idea what terminology I need to use to find the solution. In other words, I'm sorry this is probably a basic "already answered" question!!

Okay so I have this setup:

```
    myDict = {
    "first": [0,"",0],
    "second": [0,"",0],
    "third": [0,"",0]
}

dictList = *Some code to make an array of above dictionaries*

for entry in dictList:
    for i in ("first", "second", "third"):
        entry[i[1]] = "Info"
```

And the goal is to have the code make the dictionary:

```
myDict = {
        "first": [0,"Info",0],
        "second": [0,"Info",0],
        "third": [0,"Info",0]
    }
```

However this just throws an error about invalid key values because instead of the code using "i[1]" as a reference to the key "first", it is translating this as index 1 of the literal string "first". So my best articulation of this is how to designate order of operations for multiple level references.. but the result is just mathematical tutorials.

How do I format this dual level reference so that python reads "i" as the key for the dictionary rather than a literal string? And more importantly for future self sufficiency, what technical terms describe this situation?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dictList` is a list of dicts.

Each time through the loop, `entry` is (a different) one of those dicts.

`entry["first"]` would be one of lists in that dict. (Or `entry[i]`, when `i == "first"`.)

`entry["first"][1]` would be the second element of that list.

Comment: When something really simple looking isn't working, it helps to walk through it step by step, no matter how trivial those steps may seem :)

Answer (score 3):

You've got your indexing in the wrong place.

Did you mean:

```py
entry[i][1] = "Info"
```

Answer (score 3):

Python makes it even easier. You can iterate the dictionary values and modify them directly

```
myDict = {
    "first": [0,"",0],
    "second": [0,"",0],
    "third": [0,"",0]
}

for v in myDict.values():
    v[1] = "Info"

print(myDict)
```

prints

```
{'first': [0, 'Info', 0], 'second': [0, 'Info', 0], 'third': [0, 'Info', 0]}
```

Comment: My production model is more complicated than this, so I need precise control over which element in the dict I loop through, but this is a good tool to know about for the future! Thanks!